# Inserting number of rows and input post usage

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into a table in a `for` loop:

```
public function insertprolist()
{     
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post('numrows'); $i = $i + 1)
    {
        $data = array(
            'productname' => $this->input->post('proname'+$i),
            'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'+$i),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'+$i),
            'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'+$i)
        );
        return $this->db->insert('purchaseprolist', $data);   
    }
}
```

I am getting an error.

It is not getting inserted into the database table.

I have appended new rows with input fields with names such as `proname1`, `quantity1` and for the second row the input name attribute will be generated as `proname2`, `quantity2` and it goes on.

I am retrieving the number of rows in another input with name `numrows`.

Now I want to access these inputs in modal file.

Comment: please help me with this :)

Comment: What is the problem? error?

Comment: it is not getting inserted n the database table

Comment: i guess the input is not accessed properly

Comment: Post your html page and the errors your are getting

Comment: why are u using `return`

Comment: u must need to debug your post value here and concatenation is wrong here

Comment: i have appended new rows with input fields with names such as "proname1", "quantity1" and for the second row the input name attribute will be generated as "proname2","quantity2" and it goes on ! i am retreiving the number of rows in another input with name "numrows" !!!now to access these inputs in modal file is my problem :) kindly help out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'numrows' ); $i++)
{
  $data = array(
              'productname' => $this->input->post( 'proname' . $i ),
              'quantity'    => $this->input->post( 'quantity' . $i ),
              'price'       => $this->input->post( 'price' . $i ),
              'amount'      => $this->input->post( 'amount' . $i )
               );

   $this->db->insert('purchaseprolist', $data);   
 }
```

This will most likely work however it is doing an insert for each row, you would be better having a look at building an array of values and using `insert_batch()` to do that whole thing at once.

---

Better option:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'numrows' ); $i++)
{
  $data[] = array(
              'productname' => $this->input->post( 'proname' . $i ),
              'quantity'    => $this->input->post( 'quantity' . $i ),
              'price'       => $this->input->post( 'price' . $i ),
              'amount'      => $this->input->post( 'amount' . $i )
               );
 }
 $this->db->insert_batch( 'purchaseprolist', $data );
```

This will perform a single database insert query instead of looping the number of rows and performing an insert per row.  The same data will be submitted to the database only more efficiently.

Comment: thank you it worked :) i never used insert batch now this has been a learning for me :)

Comment: Glad your sorted.

Comment: yah, that one is the complete example... :) my vote for u.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use
Set your `"+"` = `"."`
PHP will understand that is a match.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post('numrows'); $i = $i + 1)
{
  $data = array(
    'productname' => $this->input->post('proname'.$i),
    'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'.$i),
    'price' => $this->input->post('price'.$i),
    'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'.$i)
);
   return $this->db->insert('purchaseprolist', $data);
}
```

Because your question is not clear, so I can only explain it to you like this.

Comment: it is not happening :(

Comment: ya my concatination is wrong :) thank you i changed it but also i had to change my query to insert batch :) thanks thou :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you are trying to `return` within the forloop. So try to remove it like below

```
public function insertprolist()
{     
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post('numrows'); $i = $i + 1)
    {
        $data = array(
            'productname' => $this->input->post('proname'+$i),
            'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'+$i),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'+$i),
            'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'+$i)
        );
        $this->db->insert('purchaseprolist', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Number: 1048

Column 'productname' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `purchaseprolist` (`productname`, `quantity`, `price`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: E:/wamp/www/CodeIgniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: then try this `'productname' => $this->input->post('proname' . $i),` the problem is your not getting the post data

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, you can not use + sign for concatenation, you need to use (.) dot here:

```
$data = array(
        'productname' => $this->input->post('proname'.$i),
        'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'.$i),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'.$i),
        'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'.$i)
        );
```

***Second***, you are using return, this will stop your function after ist iteration, you can not use it inside the `for` loop.

***Third***, before inserting, try to check your post value what are you getting this will help you understand what are you trying.

```
print_r($_POST); // before for loop start.
```

***Fourth***, instead of multiple queries execution, i suggest you to use `batch_insert()`, this will help you: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: @Ramya: the third part is very important for debuging, atleast check what are u getting from your form

Comment: my concatination was wrong :) and also when i used insert batch it worked thank you :)

Comment: @Ramya: glad to help you,  dont forgot to accept the best answer from given answers, this will help to future visitors

Comment: sure :) i only accepted the one that worked for me :)